# Solving Network Flow Using Cplex

Tags: cplex

I am trying to write a code for a network flow problem with about 100 nodes and 120 arcs. One of my constraints also involves matrix multiplication (power flow equation). However, as a beginner trying to use `CPLEX` is very challenging. Below is what I have tried so far but it is not yielding result. Kindly assist with a better way of encoding a network flow problem in `CPLEX`. Many thanks.

```
int B=...; //number of nodes

int L=...; //number of lines

range nodes =1..B;

range lines =1..L;

float cost_generation [nodes]= ...;

float cost_shedding [nodes]= ...;

float max_generation[nodes]= ...;

float load_demand[nodes] = ...;

float cost_transmission [lines]= ...;

float max_power_flow[lines] = ...;

float admittance[1..4][1..4] = ...;



dvar float+ G[nodes];

dvar float+ D[nodes];

dvar float+ F[lines];
```

minimize sum (i in nodes, k in lines)

```
(cost_generation[i]*G[i] + cost_transmission[k]*F[k] - cost_shedding[i]*D[i]);


subject to {

forall (i in nodes)

0<=G[i]<=max_generation[i];


forall (i in nodes) 

-load_demand[i]<=-D[i]<=0;


forall (k in lines)

-max_power_flow[k]<=F[k]<=max_power_flow[k];


forall (k in lines, i in nodes, j in nodes)

  sum(i in nodes, j in nodes)

admittance[i][j]*G[j]-D[j]==F[i];

  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "is not yielding result"? Does the code give a syntax error or an error at runtime, or does it report that the problem is infeasible or unbounded, or does it take too long to give an answer?
The setup for the last constraint looks 'wrong' too - you have a sum over all pairs of nodes for every line and combination of pairs of nodes which will generate 120x100x100 constraints, each with about 100x100 terms, i.e. 1.2 million constraints with about 10000 terms in each.

Comment: Tim, thanks for your comment. I have updated the last constraint but still getting undefined results. 


forall (k in lines, i in nodes)

 sum(i in nodes)

admittance[i][k]*(G[i]-D[i])==F[k];


All my decision variables are zero. Probably, i'm getting the whole code wrong. Please, how can I write a code for a network flow problem with 24 nodes and 38 arcs that has matrix (24 X 38) as its constraint. Please assist, thanks.

Comment: How are the lines related to the nodes? I would expect something about the nodes on each line and/or the lines meeting at a node? That is kind-of typical for a network problem.

Comment: You are very right sir. It is a typical network problem such that a line connects two nodes.

Comment: admittance[i][k] means that node (i1) is connected to all the nodes in the network (i1, i2, i3 ... i24) through lines (k1, k2, k3 ... k38). This is repeated for all the nodes and the matrix is formed.